# What is this verse in Garbha Upanishad trying to say?

Tags: scripture, upanishads, children

[Garbha Upanishad](http://www.ece.lsu.edu/kak/GarbhaUpanishad.pdf) mentions following:

> If the father’s seed is more potent, it becomes male; if the mother’s
>   seed is stronger, it becomes female. If the seeds are equal, it
>   becomes an intersexual.

So how is the gender related to whether male or female seed is stronger?

Comment: Not only Garbha Upanishad many Hindu scriptures say the same .. IMO what is said can not be linked to chromosomes .. it is Shukla (or Shukra/father) and Rakta (blood/mother)

Comment: @Rickross so the potency of Shukra and Rakta decides the gender of the child?

Comment: @TheDestroyer That's an amazing explanation :O .. is it true?

Comment: @Rickross Yes. Read that in a book and Garuda Purana too. Not sure if i can post that as an answer.

Comment: Yes post an answer then .. @TheDestroyer

Comment: @TheDestroyer I've removed the chromosome part.

Comment: @user5155835 I don't exactly knw what it means but it  can not be linked with chromosome and in many scriptures I read the same

Comment: @Rickross I've removed the chromosomes part

Comment: @TheDestroyer Please can you post this as answer with reference?

Comment: I think Manu smriti says something similar, I don't remember the exact verse though.

Comment: See, we cannot take all these biological details in the Upanishads as literal truth, when we know now from modern science about genetics. Upanishads are meant for metaphysical/spiritual knowledge. Not all the physical theories in Upanishads are correct.